# "A newer version of the AWS SAM CLI is available!" error when running a Lambda function locally in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-cloud9

I am trying to run a function locally in Cloud9 IDE and I keep getting this error. If I run it remotely it works fine.

I installed the latest version of `aws-sam-cli`. When I run `$sam --version`, I get SAM CLI, version 0.8.0, which is neither the version in the error or the one I installed.

I also tried uninstalling `aws-sam-cli`, reinstalling `aws-cli`, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Node.js version. I set up the function in Lambda using version 10.x when the Cloud9 only works with version 8.10. Once I changed it to version 8.10 in Lambda the problem was resolved.